# Error 'Target container is not a DOM element' importing react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I want to try to test react hook (in this case it isn't hook yet, I just tried simple function as component). I have this index.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function increaseCount() {
    setCount(count => count + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 data-count>count: {count}</h1>
      <button onClick={increaseCount}>increase</button>
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Counter />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The app run well, then I add this index.spec.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Counter } from "./index"; //this line caused problem

test("Test", () => {
  console.log("Counter", Counter);
});
```

Then I got error of

```
Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.
```

What's wrong?

Update:

I separated Counter into another file, it worked, I wonder why I can't use multiple import in App.js

Comment: You can have multiple exports from App.js. Your problem is likely somewhere else. I see you're importing from `./index`, not App. Is it possible that in `index` you're rendering App?

Comment: @Gpx No, the issue got resolved when I moved Counter function to a new file, that surprised me.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to use `it` instead of `test`
[here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests) you can checkout

Comment: nope. That's not the problem. I put Counter function separately as a file, the issue is gone, I'm not sure why I can't export it as object in App.js.

Comment: `it` is an alias for `test` you can use the one you prefer